Weka 3.8.6 Java Heap Size Problem on Mac. VMOptions modification in Info.plist didn't work
I read the questions about Weka Java Heap Space Problem, but they couldn't solve my problem. I modified Info.plist file like
<key>VMOptions</key> <string>-Xmx16384</string>
I have a huge dataset, that's why I need at least 10GB memory. Because I have 38GB RAM (McBook Pro M3 Processor) I would like to increase the heap size to 16 GB. When I started GUI Chooser I still see this info:
enter image description here
I also tried to open Info.plist. I had this error message:
(base) hurolturen@Hurols-MBP Contents % open Info.plist  No application knows how to open URL file:///Applications/weka-3.8.6.app/Contents/Info.plist (Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10814 "kLSApplicationNotFoundErr: E.g. no application claims the file" UserInfo={_LSLine=1741, _LSFunction=runEvaluator}). (base) hurolturen@Hurols-MBP Contents % vim Info.plist  
Can anyone help me please?
I tried to modify Info.plist to adjust the Java Heap Size to 16 GB but it is still 9 GB which is not enough for me. I also changed the Heap Size of the whole system to 16 GB but it didn't work either.

I'm on Linux, so not familiar with the Mac intricacies...
If you want the highest level of control over your JVM, open a bash terminal, navigate to the directory where your weka.jar is located and then run this using Java 11:
java -Xmx16g -jar weka.jar

Rather than supplying the heap size via parameter to the JVM, you can also do that via the _JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable. See also this article on the Weka wiki.

This is also what I tried. It didn’t work either.

Wenn I write this command I receive
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
at weka.gui.SplashWindow.invokeMain(SplashWindow.java:306)
at weka.gui.GUIChooser.main(GUIChooser.java:92)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The Security Manager is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)

What Java version are you using? Try 11 LTS.

Thanks very much. I downgraded my Java version from 21 to 11 LTS. It worked.

Great! I updated my answer to include a note about using Java 11.
